# Rails Routes: change resource identifier path name? always use params[:model_id] instead of params[:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not sure how to ask this question...

But i'm working with nested ROUTES as shown below.

I like knowing that the **Business ID** can always be found using `params[:business_id]`, obviously except for the actual business controller which requires me to use `params[:id]`.

Is there a way to change the route resource id param to always be `:business_id` instead of having to be like `Business.find(params.values_at(:business_id, :id).first)`??

```
                  business_exports GET    /businesses/:business_id/exports(.:format)                                                                                businesses/exports#index
                                   POST   /businesses/:business_id/exports(.:format)                                                                                businesses/exports#create
               new_business_export GET    /businesses/:business_id/exports/new(.:format)                                                                            businesses/exports#new
              edit_business_export GET    /businesses/:business_id/exports/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                       businesses/exports#edit
                   business_export GET    /businesses/:business_id/exports/:id(.:format)                                                                            businesses/exports#show
                                   PATCH  /businesses/:business_id/exports/:id(.:format)                                                                            businesses/exports#update
                                   PUT    /businesses/:business_id/exports/:id(.:format)                                                                            businesses/exports#update
                                   DELETE /businesses/:business_id/exports/:id(.:format)                                                                            businesses/exports#destroy
           business_replenishments GET    /businesses/:business_id/replenishments(.:format)                                                                         businesses/replenishments#index
             business_offer_prices GET    /businesses/:business_id/offer_prices(.:format)                                                                           businesses/offer_prices#index
                                   POST   /businesses/:business_id/offer_prices(.:format)                                                                           businesses/offer_prices#create
       business_unmatched_listings GET    /businesses/:business_id/unmatched_listings(.:format)                                                                     businesses/unmatched_listings#index
                                   POST   /businesses/:business_id/unmatched_listings(.:format)                                                                     businesses/unmatched_listings#create
      business_profit_loss_reports GET    /businesses/:business_id/profit_loss_reports(.:format)                                                                    businesses/profit_loss_reports#index
                        businesses GET    /businesses(.:format)                                                                                                     businesses#index
                                   POST   /businesses(.:format)                                                                                                     businesses#create
                      new_business GET    /businesses/new(.:format)                                                                                                 businesses#new
                     edit_business GET    /businesses/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                                            businesses#edit
                          business GET    /businesses/:id(.:format)                                                                                                 businesses#show
                                   PATCH  /businesses/:id(.:format)                                                                                                 businesses#update
                                   PUT    /businesses/:id(.:format)                                                                                                 businesses#update
                                   DELETE /businesses/:id(.:format)                                                                                                 businesses#destroy
```

Comment: I've added an answer to your question, however, as a side note, you should ask yourself why you want to sway away from Rails' default of `:id` as the dynamic segment on the latter routes.

Comment: I want to share a top level authentication controller at the BUSINESS level and shouldn't have to toggle back and forth between `params[:id]` and `params[:business_id]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Rails 4+ you can do this using the `param` option in the `resources` method

[Overriding Route Parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters)

Assuming you have code that looks like

```
resources :businesses
```

You can add an argument as such

```
resources :businesses, param: :business_id
```

Which should generate routes

```
                    businesses GET    /businesses(.:format)                                                                                                     businesses#index
                               POST   /businesses(.:format)                                                                                                     businesses#create
                  new_business GET    /businesses/new(.:format)                                                                                                 businesses#new
                 edit_business GET    /businesses/:business_id/edit(.:format)                                                                                            businesses#edit
                      business GET    /businesses/:business_id(.:format)                                                                                                 businesses#show
                               PATCH  /businesses/:business_id(.:format)                                                                                                 businesses#update
                               PUT    /businesses/:business_id(.:format)                                                                                                 businesses#update
                               DELETE /businesses/:business_id(.:format)
```

**UPDATE**

Since you're generating these routes using the same nested resources you'll have to do the following

```
resources :businesses, param: :business_id 
resources :businesses, only: [] do
  resources :exports
  ...
end
```

Comment: HI @leo that doesn't work because the nested routes will have `params[:business_business_id]`

Comment: At that point you'd have to separate the nested resources and duplicate the `resources` routes. It'd be more helpful if you show how your routes are laid out.

Comment: BINGO - i have not seen this anywhere. You win internet points!

Answer (score 1):

A more clean way is to use the `member`

```rb
resources :businesses, param: :business_id do
  member do
    resources :exports
    ...
  end
end
```